# How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

How do I find the application's path in a console application?

In [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), I can use `Application.StartupPath` to find the current path, but this doesn't seem to be available in a console application.

Comment: Do you install .NET Framework on target (Client, Development) machine? if your answer is true; So, you can add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll and use Application.StartupPath! This is the best way if you want to drop away further future exceptions!

Comment: AppDomain.BaseDirectory is app directory. Be aware that application can behave different in VS env and Win env. But AppDomain should be same not as application.path but i hope that this is not only for IIS.

Answer (score 1354, accepted):

[`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly).[`Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location)<sup>1</sup>

Combine that with [`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname) if all you want is the directory.

> <sup>1</sup>*As per Mr.Mindor's comment:*
>   `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returns where the executing assembly is currently located, which may or may not be where the assembly is located when not executing. In the case of shadow copying assemblies, you will get a path in a temp directory. [`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.codebase) will return the 'permanent' path of the assembly.

Comment: FYI, when I run this from an IIS web app I get this result... 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a897dd66\ec73ff95\assembly\dl3\ff65202d\e9a4e8db_5d84cc01

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location returns where the executing assembly is **currently** located, which may or may not be where the assembly is located when not executing. In the case of shadow copying assemblies, you will get a path in a temp directory. System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase will return the '__permenant__' path of the assembly.

Comment: Personally I might be thinking that reflection is overkill for this sort of thing when we have Environment.GetCommandLineArgs. But maybe I'm wrong and should go and do the tests.

Comment: The command line arguments are not guaranteed to contain the application being launched.  It is entirely possible that the application or a loaded dll can blow that information away.  see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/15/597984.aspx

Comment: @Boo Ok fair enough point. But we are talking about a console application. The link does more or less say that this is a theoretical problem. And why would you run a console application in this way?

Comment: @SteveMc: why remember two (or more) ways of doing something when one way will suffice for all applications.

Comment: @Boo. You will have to do that anyway if you create ASP.net apps

Comment: @Mr.Mindor: except that the CodeBase property returns a URI, not a directory which can be used as a file path, so that is not a full solution.

Comment: @SamGoldberg: That depend on how it is used: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1068420/391656 . Or you can ...

    new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath

Comment: For whatever reason, in VS2013 (at least the copy I have) intellisense does not work past System.Reflection.Assembly. GetExeuctingAssembly() is there but you cannot see it.

Comment: I have a console application project with NUnit tests in the same project. At run-time the solution works OK. But when I run the tests by Resharper test runner or NUnit GUI runner, `GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returns a path like this: `d:\Temp\f4ctjcmr.ofr\nojeuppd.fmf\R2Nbs\assembly\dl3\9766f38e\b9496fb3_43cccf01\`.  <br/> Disabling shadow-copying fixed the problem in both Test runners, but new problems appeared (VS is not able to build the project until NUnit Gui is closed...

Comment: `GetExecutingAssembly` returns assembly that **contains the code that is currently executing**. This may not necessarily be the console **.exe** assembly. It may be an assembly that has been loaded from a totally different location. You will have to use `GetEntryAssembly`! Also note that `CodeBase`might not be set when the assembly is in the GAC. The better alternative is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Comment: Notice that this will prepend a "file:" string to your path for some reason.

Comment: if you call dll,  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase   will get  "file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll"

Comment: Using `Application.StartupPath` would be the easiest solution here. Also posted it as an answer below (way below) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @farosch: `Application` doesn't exist for console applications.

Comment: I do not understand at all why this is marked as the correct answer. It does not work in all the scenarios, the command line inspection through the environment does work.

Comment: You'll probably have to strip of the 'file:\' prefix for 'CodeBase'; e.g.:

                var assCodeBasePath =
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(
                            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
                        .Replace(
                            @"file:\",
                            string.Empty);

Comment: A decade later, .NET Core say CodeBase is obsolete and we should use Locaction.

Answer (score 482):

You can use the following code to get the current application directory.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: Nifty tip especially when using embedded resources

Comment: Don't use this. The BaseDirectory can be set at runtime. It is not guaranteed to be correct (like the accepted answer is).

Comment: +1 This is likely the answer you want as it compensates for shadow copying.

Comment: @usr What makes you think that `BaseDirectory` can be set at runtime? It only has a getter.

Comment: @bitbonk it can be set at appdomain creation time.

Comment: Isn't it that BaseDirectory can be changed in a *.lnk file, in the "Start in:" field?

Comment: I tried and it works if you are working with Console App using .NET 6.0, while the code from the  accepted answer returns null.

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. When installing the application in the Program Files folder, the System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location is empty.

Comment: When using single file publish this is the right way to get it.

Answer (score 216):

You have two options for finding the directory of the application, which you choose will depend on your purpose.

```
// To get the location the assembly is executing from
// (not necessarily where it normally resides on disk).
// In the case of using shadow copies, for instance in NUnit tests, 
// this will be in a temp directory.
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

// To get the location the assembly normally resides on disk or the install directory
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;

// Once you have the path you get the directory with:
var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Comment: Just wanted to say, obviously there are many more than 2 options by how many other choices are posted...

Comment: If whatever you're trying to do with said path doesn't support URI format, use `var localDirectory = new Uri(directory).LocalPath;`

Comment: This is just wrong. What is the executable is not a .NET assembly at all? The right answer is to check the environment and inspect the command line.

Comment: @Ukuma.Scott This doesn't work if the path contains & or #

Comment: @mark Would you please tell what the actual code is ?

Comment: @Grace - This was so long. If your exe is just a .NET app, then the proposed approach should be good enough.

Answer (score 100):

Probably a bit late but this is worth a mention:

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
```

Or more correctly to get just the directory path:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
```

**Edit:**

Quite a few people have pointed out that `GetCommandLineArgs` is not guaranteed to return the program name. See [The first word on the command line is the program name only by convention](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/15/597984.aspx). The article does state that "Although extremely few Windows programs use this quirk (I am not aware of any myself)". So it is possible to 'spoof' `GetCommandLineArgs`, but we are talking about a console application. Console apps are usually quick and dirty. So this fits in with my KISS philosophy.

**Edit**
It seems, from feedback, that most of the other solutions don't work when you are using a unit testing system. This sort of makes sense as the executable item is not your application, but the testing system.

Comment: And maybe this: path = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0].Substring(0, iniFilePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

Comment: @fabspro - I've edited the post to show the extra step of removing the application name and just leaving the directory path

Comment: This is not good advice. args[0] is not guaranteed to be the exe path. It could just be the exe name, or anything else the process creator chooses. Don't use this!

Comment: @usr the situation you allude to is highly theoretical. In the context of a console application, it doesn't really make sense to use any other method. Keep it simple!

Comment: @SteveMc, look into the cmdline column in taskmgr and you see multiple processes where this is the case! For me: splwow64, winlogon, taskeng. This is a practical problem, and a better solution exists. No offense to you.

Comment: @usr mmm - looking at the taskmgr cmdline column sort of backs up what I'm saying. A few system services with just the exe name. Never mind. What I'm trying to say is that when developing a console application there is no need to make things more complicated than they need to be. Especially when we already have the information available. Now, if you are running a console application in such a way as to trick GetCommandLineArgs then you are already jumping through hoops and you would probably need to ask yourself if a console app is the right way to go.

Comment: Your "simple" solution involves two method calls. The "complicated" solution involves two method calls. No practical difference - except that the "simple" solution can give you the wrong answer under certain circumstances which aren't under your control when you're writing the program. Why take the risk? Use the other two method calls, and your program will be no more complicated but will be more reliable.

Comment: Worked for my scenario, the other solutions did not, so thanks for providing another alternative :-)  I was using ReSharper test runner to run an MS Unit test and the code I was testing needed a specific .dll to be in the executing directory...and Assembly.GetExecutingDirectory() weirdly returns a different result.

Comment: Correct your answers  .Io System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]); With capital IO

Comment: @Chris - to the defense of this answer. It works for unit tests, the GetEntryAssembly solution does not, because GetEntryAssembly returns null. The answers which propose GetExecutingAssembly are bogus, because they only return the executable if the executing assembly is the executable. This is not the simple, but the correct solution.

Answer (score 51):

For anyone interested in asp.net web apps. Here are my results of 3 different methods

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string p1 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
  string p2 = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
  string p3 = this.Server.MapPath("");
  Console.WriteLine("p1 = " + p1);
  Console.WriteLine("p2 = " + p2);
  Console.WriteLine("p3 = " + p3);
}
```

result

```
p1 = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a897dd66\ec73ff95\assembly\dl3\ff65202d\29daade3_5e84cc01
p2 = C:\inetpub\SBSPortal_staging\
p3 = C:\inetpub\SBSPortal_staging
```

the app is physically running from "C:\inetpub\SBSPortal_staging", so the first solution is definitely not appropriate for web apps.

Answer (score 47):

The answer above was 90% of what I needed, but returned a Uri instead of a regular path for me.

As explained in the MSDN forums post, [How to convert URI path to normal filepath?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/csharplanguage/thread/9341a48b-5c23-4b54-a354-2e21732cbea5), I used the following:

```
// Get normal filepath of this assembly's permanent directory
var path = new Uri(
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
    ).LocalPath;
```

Comment: this works well also if the exe in question is a windows service  and current directory returns C:\Windows\system32.   The above code returns the actual location of the exe

Comment: Except if you then try to do something like `File.CreateDirectory(path)`, it will give you the exception that it doesn't allow URI paths...

Comment: Unfortunately this is doesn't work for paths that contain a fragment identifier (the `#` character). The identifier and everything following it is truncated from the resulting path.

Comment: Why don't you swap `new Uri` and `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`? That gives you a normal path string instead of a `Uri`.

Comment: I find this the best one. This same approach has worked reliably for me in any environment. In production, debugging locally, unit testing... Want to open a content file that you included ("content - copy if newer") in a unit test? It's there.

Answer (score 43):

If you are looking for a .NET Core compatible way, use

```
System.AppContext.BaseDirectory
```

This was introduced in .NET Framework 4.6 and .NET Core 1.0 (and .NET Standard 1.3). See: [AppContext.BaseDirectory Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory?view=netframework-4.7.1).

According to [this page](http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/6-ways-to-get-the-current-directory-in-csharp/),

> This is the prefered replacement for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory in .NET Core

Comment: see also https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13051 for self-contained dotnet console apps. The recommendation here is to use `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`

Comment: @Gavin This was true till .NET 5. With .NET 5 or above use AppContext.BaseDirectory. 
 see https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-do-i-find-which-directory-my-net-core-console-application-was-started-in-or-is-running-from

Comment: This is the correct answer! It works if you are trying it in local, and also if you deployed a console application into a scheduled task.

Answer (score 32):

You may be looking to do this:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

Comment: Note this brought back a URI, which isn't supported in all cases.

Answer (score 29):

you can use this one instead.

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Comment: This will get the folder of the executable though

Comment: This can be changed in number of ways(shortcut settings etc)... better to NOT use it.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub but if the person specified a different starting directory, this would honor their request to use all configuration files within that directory.

Answer (score 22):

For Console Applications, you can try this:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Output (on my local machine):

> c:\users\xxxxxxx\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ImageHandler\GetDir\bin\Debug

Or you can try (there's an additional backslash in the end):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Output:

> c:\users\xxxxxxx\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ImageHandler\GetDir\bin\Debug\

Comment: "The `BaseDirectory` can be set at runtime. It is NOT guaranteed to be correct"

Answer (score 18):

I have used this code and get the solution.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 15):

Following line will give you an application path:

```
var applicationPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
```

Above solution is working properly in the following situations:

- simple app
- in another domain where Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() would return null
- DLL is loaded from Embedded resources as a byte array and loaded to AppDomain as Assembly.Load(byteArrayOfEmbeddedDll)
- with Mono's `mkbundle` bundles (no other methods work)

Comment: Under debugger on linux this returns: /usr/share/dotnet

Answer (score 9):

You can simply add to your project references `System.Windows.Forms` and then use the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath`  as usual .

So, not need for more complicated methods or using the reflection.

Comment: I used that one, and it works well. But one time I used the method having it in my unit test project. And of course, it failed because it was looking for my file in C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW

Comment: @ainasiart so how do i get this to work while unit testing??

Answer (score 8):

I have used

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

when I want to find a path relative to an applications folder. This works for both ASP.Net and winform applications. It also does not require any reference to System.Web assemblies.

Answer (score 7):

I mean, why not a P/Invoke method?

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class AppInfo
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = false)]
    private static extern int GetModuleFileName(HandleRef hModule, StringBuilder buffer, int length);
    private static HandleRef NullHandleRef = new HandleRef(null, IntPtr.Zero);
    public static string StartupPath
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(260);
            GetModuleFileName(NullHandleRef, stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(stringBuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it just like the `Application.StartupPath`:

```
Console.WriteLine("The path to this executable is: " + AppInfo.StartupPath + "\\" + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe");
```

Comment: Why p/invoke when there is so much .NET for this?

Comment: @user3596865 because it requries a hard dependency to Windows and is not compatible with DNX or Mono. And maybe there is a breaking change in future Windows Versions. So again: why we should use pinvoke here?

Answer (score 7):

I didn't see anyone convert the LocalPath provided by .Net Core reflection into a usable System.IO path so here's my version.

```
public static string GetApplicationRoot()
{
   var exePath = new Uri(System.Reflection.
   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;

   return new FileInfo(exePath).DirectoryName;
       
}
```

This will return the full `C:\\xxx\\xxx` formatted path to where your code is.

Comment: I fail to understand how `Uri(System.Reflection.
   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath` is any different then `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 7):

For .NET 6 there is `Environment.ProcessPath`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processpath?view=net-6.0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30422998)

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey They're giving a solution and a reference to the documentation that says that is in fact a solution. How would you reference a solution without using a link?

Comment: @Scratte He did not mean that the link should be left away; instead, he says *... and provide the link for reference.* It is common sense here on SO that **link-only** answers may become useless very fast, because links targets tend to vanish fast. So indeed it's best to post the link, but additionally try to incorporate at least the most essential information from the page the link refers to.

Comment: @Binarus They did. They said ".NET 6 there's Environment.ProcessPath", which is the  "essential part". That's all one needs to know to move on to a solution. The link is just a reference to "Environment.ProcessPath". It's extra, so people who don't need to google "Environment.ProcessPath". Did you click on the link? What exactly do you think should be copy'n'pasted from it?

Comment: Well, you're probably right in this case. I just was trying to explain what Erik McKelvey was meaning (in response to your first comment).

Answer (score 6):

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` or `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Use in combination with `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` to get only the directory.

The paths from `GetEntryAssembly()` and `GetExecutingAssembly()` can be different, even though for most cases the directory will be the same.

With `GetEntryAssembly()` you have to be aware that this can return `null` if the entry module is unmanaged (ie C++ or VB6 executable). In those cases it is possible to use `GetModuleFileName` from the Win32 API:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetModuleFileName(HandleRef hModule, StringBuilder buffer, int length);
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this if the exe is supposed to be called by double clicking it

```
var thisPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Comment: This is not correct because you can get random directories in result.

Comment: this Command returns Environment.CurrentDirectory, which may be changed at runtime to any path, so it is not a reliable solution.

Answer (score 6):

in VB.net

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

works for me (Application Type: Class Library). Not sure about C#...
Returns the path w/o Filename as string

Answer (score 5):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Will resolve the issue to refer the 3rd party reference files with installation packages.

Comment: This answer has already been suggested 5 years ago, even more than once.

Answer (score 5):

With .NET Core 3 and above you will get the .dll and not the .exe file. To get the .exe file path you can use.

```
var appExePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this simple line of code:

```
 string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName( Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 6, my WPF app (`<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`) returns the `.dll` file path for `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.Location` instead of the `.exe` file. They introduced [`System.Environment.ProcessPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processpath?view=net-6.0) for this purpose:

```cs
var path = Environment.ProcessPath; // Note it may be null
```

> Returns the path of the executable that started the currently executing process. Returns `null` when the path is not available.

See discussion for it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40862) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13051).

Answer (score 2):

None of these methods work in special cases like using a symbolic link to the exe, they will return the location of the link not the actual exe.

So can use [QueryFullProcessImageName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx) to get around that:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName([In]IntPtr hProcess, [In]int dwFlags, [Out]StringBuilder lpExeName, ref int lpdwSize);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
        UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        Boolean bInheritHandle,
        Int32 dwProcessId
    );
}

public static class utils
{

    private const UInt32 PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x400;
    private const UInt32 PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x010;

    public static string getfolder()
    {
        Int32 pid = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        int capacity = 2000;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(capacity);
        IntPtr proc;

        if ((proc = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid)) == IntPtr.Zero)
            return "";

        NativeMethods.QueryFullProcessImageName(proc, 0, sb, ref capacity);

        string fullPath = sb.ToString(0, capacity);

        return Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath) + @"\";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)`
Is the only one that has worked for me in every case I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The techniques, and pitfalls, keep changing. The below assumes you're running a .NET 6 console app on linux (on win/mac the results will follow a similar pattern, just replace `/usr/share/` and `/home/username/` with the standard locations for your OS).

Demo:

```
Console.WriteLine("Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess()?.MainModule?.FileName) = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess()?.MainModule?.FileName));
Console.WriteLine("Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.ProcessPath)                           = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.ProcessPath));
Console.WriteLine("Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)          = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
Console.WriteLine("typeof(SomeType).Assembly.Location                                       = " + typeof(SomeType).Assembly.Location);
Console.WriteLine("Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0])               = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]));
Console.WriteLine("AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory                                    = " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
Console.WriteLine("System.AppContext.BaseDirectory                                          = " + System.AppContext.BaseDirectory);
```

Results:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess()?.MainModule?.FileName) = /usr/share/dotnet
Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.ProcessPath)                           = /usr/share/dotnet
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)          = /home/username/myproject/bin/Debug/net6.0
typeof(SomeType).Assembly.Location                                       = /home/username/myproject/bin/Debug/net6.0
Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0])               = /home/username/myproject/bin/Debug/net6.0
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory                                    = /home/username/myproject/bin/Debug/net6.0/
System.AppContext.BaseDirectory                                          = /home/username/myproject/bin/Debug/net6.0/
```

Each approach has its own pros and cons - see the other answers to learn in which uses cases to use which approach.

I run my .NET 6 console app with `dotnet myapp`, so what works (reliably) for me is either of:

```cs
typeof(SomeType).Assembly.Location
// or
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reliable solution that works with **32bit** and **64bit** applications.

Add these references:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;
```

Add this method to your project:

```
public static string GetProcessPath(int processId)
{
    string MethodResult = "";
    try
    {
        string Query = "SELECT ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId;

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get())
            {
                string ExecutablePath = (from mo in moc.Cast<ManagementObject>() select mo["ExecutablePath"]).First().ToString();
                MethodResult = ExecutablePath;
            }
        }
    }
    catch //(Exception ex)
    {
        //ex.HandleException();
    }
    return MethodResult;
}
```

Now use it like so:

```
int RootProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
GetProcessPath(RootProcessId);
```

Notice that if you know the id of the process, then this method will return the corresponding ExecutePath.

**Extra, for those interested:**

```
Process.GetProcesses()
```

...will give you an array of all the currently running processes, and...

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess()
```

...will give you the current process, along with their information e.g. Id, etc. and also limited control e.g. Kill, etc.*

Answer (score 0):

I use this for console + net 6

```cs
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Answer (score -5):

You can create a folder name as Resources within the project using Solution Explorer,then you can paste a file within the Resources.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string appName = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    int l = appName.Length;
    int h = appName.LastIndexOf("bin");
    string ll = appName.Remove(h);                
    string g = ll + "Resources\\sample.txt";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(g);
}
```

Comment: Using Environment.CurrentDirectory is very wrong, don't use this! this path can change at runtime. Even at startup it is non-deterministic.