# Is there an easy way to open a Uri and get whatever it points to? (C#)

Tags: c#, uri

I have a `Uri` object being passed to a constructor of my class.

I want to open the file the `Uri` points to, whether it's local, network, http, whatever, and read the contents into a string. Is there an easy way of doing this, or do I have to try to work off things like `Uri.IsFile` to figure out how to try to open it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
static string GetContents(Uri uri) {
    using (var response = WebRequest.Create(uri).GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

It won't work for **whatever**. It works for `file://`, `http://` and `https://` and `ftp://` by default. However, you can register custom URI handlers with [`WebRequest.RegisterPrefix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix.aspx) to make it work for those as well.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is by using the WebClient class:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string contents = client.DownloadString(uri);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it's not thread-safe, which is an issue, and from what I can see from a quick glance, it only supports HTTP (I need atleast file:// too)

Comment: @Matthew: Internally, it just uses `WebRequest` so it supports file:// and ftp:// too. If you need more control, you should use `WebRequest` directly. If you just want a string back, use `WebClient`.

Comment: It does support other URIs. It's not limited to HTTP. And what do you mean by not being thread-safe?

Comment: If you need multiple threads - use multiple `WebClient` instances. There is no thread safety issue here...