# Detecting the startup path of a C# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know the application startup path for C# 2.0 windows form application. One way is Application.StartupPath. Is there another way to find the application startup path?

Comment: Why do you need to use anything other than Application.StartupPath?

Comment: If you already have one way, why do you want another?

Comment: If your asking this question, it leads me to believe the Application.StartupPath is not returning what you expect. Is this for Visual Studio Tools for Office, if so which version?

Comment: The application startup path is not necessarily the directory the binaries are in. Perhaps that is what OP is really after.

Comment: I wanted to check my application using different options to see how will they function under different circumstances. I though knowing different options will help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BasePath)

Comment: That will work most times, but what if you are executing in another AppDomain?

Answer (score 6):

Look at this: [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-c-in-a-console-app)