# Relative path on console application

Tags: relative-path

I've an old program that use relative path to get mail templates. 
The relative path point to local folder on the project folder . 
My problem is that the program transalte the relative path to c:\windows\system32... . 
The os is server 2008 . 
There is any configuration work around that i need to do ?

Thanks in advance ,

Ishay .

Comment: Possibly related Q/answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function for converting relative path to full path, but pay attention **YOU SHOULD NOT USE THIS FUNCTION IF YOUR PROGRAMM IS MULTITHREADED**