# How do i find the absolute path of the exe file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the application's path in .NET in a console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app)

Hi,

I would like to find the absolute path from where my exe file is running.

i.e if i run my application/exe from c:\my-app\myapp.exe then it should return c:\my-app.

My target is to find my database location inside the db folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase` gives you the name of the exe, and `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(...)` then pulls the directory part out.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx#howtoexecutingapppath_topic2