# Application path

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the application's path in .NET in a console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app)

How can I get application path? (folder the executable is in)

Comment: @Pranay: Please stop begging for accepts. This is the first question this user has asked, and the [system isn't even going to let them accept an answer yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099). I feel like I've asked you this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Determine the Executing Application's Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

```
   path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Brad Abrams site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/14/113620.aspx), you might want to look at this code:

```
Console.WriteLine (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
```

Or, from comments in that link:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
```