# Passing c# command line arguments in a batch file

Tags: c#, command-line, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I have build a c# code which would basically take four arguments a1 a2 a3 a4. I am trying to make a batch file so that the user can enter his arguments and code gives the particular output. I am not sure how do i send these arguments to a batch file. i tried creating exe but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send arguments to a batch file, you do invoke it from the command line (or from another batch file) like this:

> myfile.bat a1 a2 a3

Within the batch file, the arguments are represented by %1, %2, %3 (etc.), so within the batch file you would invoke your exe like this:

> myapp.exe %1 %2 %3

That would pass the original arguments to the batch file, a1 a2 a3, along to the executable.

From within the executable you can access the arguments from your Main function

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

The arguments, a1, a2, a3, would be in args[0], args[1] and args[2] respectively.

Comment: So if i give %1 %2 %3 to make the batch file then from the command line try giving myfile.bat a1 a2 a3 will it work?

Comment: Yeah, it should.   And if your 'arguments' have spaces, you'll want to use double-quotes", i.e. "Argument 1 With Spaces", a2, a3

Comment: sure thanks. i have got another doubt. in case i pass files is there a way where i can just specify the filename instead of whole path as arguments? i mean by making the path generic to all the systems?

Comment: You can use relative paths (e.g. a path under where the .exe is installed... though users typically can't EDIT files stored there due to default permissions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app), you can use a subfolder of the ApplicationData special folder (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx), or you can configure a base path to your files in app.config.  Then, use Path.Combine(myBasePath, a1) to get a full path to your file.

Comment: Hi i am getting an error. Index was out of boundary error though I am entering my args properly