# Creating database with Linq-to-SQL to change the path

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I managed to create a database using Linq-to-SQL with the following code:

```
private static DataClasses1DataContext _dataDC = new DataClasses1DataContext(@"C:\\database1.mdf");

public AddClient()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
       _dataDC.CreateDatabase();
}
```

and this created a new local database on C: .

How can I change the `@"C:\\database1.mdf"` so that the file is created in the current directory from where I run the program ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these that suits your application and pass it in to `new DataClasses1DataContext(HERE);`

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Environment.CurrentDirectory;

Request.PhysicalPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here how to ge the current directory path. Incude it inside parentheses:

[How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app)