# force execute from local computer

Tags: .net

I have packaged a .NET application in the form of a .zip file.
The user needs to unzip the file on his local hard drive to create a directory with an executable and associated resources.
However, users keep unzipping the file on a network drive and execute the app from there, and they get problems because of this.

Can I force users to run the file from their local hard drive by displaying a message if they run it from a network drive and closing the app ?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app.  Once you know the path you could determine whether it is a network location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to check if the path is a network path and give an error message.

Steps:

1. Get path or running application:

   `var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`
2. Check if path is a network path:

   `[DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]`

   `private static extern bool PathIsNetworkPath(string pszPath);`

   `if(PathIsNetworkPath(path))...`
3. Give error message

Refer: [PathIsNetworkPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773640%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Pretty neat, thanks! This is surpringingly easy for Win32, haha.