# Converting a hard disk path to application folder path

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

How do I convert a path from my drive to an application path? Currently I am creating and accessing files on my hard disk (eg: "D:\MyFolder\MyDoc.doc"). I want this path inside my console application folder. I know I can use `Server.MapPath` for ASP.NET applications. What about console applications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app

Comment: What do you mean with "convert"?

Comment: Sorry,Actually not convert. I just want this inside application folder. Currently I am using this in hard drive.

Comment: Using System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ; I can get the debug folder. But how to retrieve the folder and files that I created inside the application.

Comment: Are you trying to take an absolute path like `D:\something\something` and convert it to a path relative to your applications current working directory like ` ..\..\something\somthing\ ` ?

Comment: No.Actually for development purpose i saved my files on harddisk. Now i want to deploy it to server. So I want to change the file paths to app path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

If you want to read file from your current folder

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetFile("filename");
```

or you want to get directory path

```
 string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            var parentdir = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(directory);
```

Comment: Is it possible to access a new folder which is created before the bin folder?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid hardcoding path file, put `MyDoc.doc` in execution folder, then you can get execution folder by  using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`:

```
string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string fileName = Path.Combine(directory, "MyDoc.doc");
```

Other alternative:

```
string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Or:

```
string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Or:

```
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

To get `bin` folder:

```
 var bin = Directory.GetParent(directory ).Parent.FullName;
```

Comment: I am using vs 2005. So I cannot use var keyword.What to do?string will work?

Comment: But these codes are returning me debug folder.D:\Projects\WebDataReceiver\WebDataReceiver\bin\Debug. Isnt it possible to get bin folder itself?