# Get absolute path of relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  am calling a method in C# as follows:

```
return Chart.RenderChartHTML("../../Charts/MSLine.swf");
```

The thing is that the path can be different depending on what folder I am calling RenderChartHTML from.

I tried the following so that it finds the absolute path but not working:

```
string mslinepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Charts/MSLine.swf");

return Chart.RenderChartHTML(mslinepath);
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[ResolveUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx)**. It converts a URL into one that is usable on the requesting client.

So Try this instead :

```
string mslinepath = ResolveUrl("~/Charts/MSLine.swf")
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Thanks. Why do I need the ~ for though?

Comment: "~" refers get the relative path from "root" directory and "." refers get the relative path from current directory.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need the `~/`. Just `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Charts/MSLine.swf");`