# What does args 0 store in this program

Tags: c#

What does this code do in this example, what does `args[0]` store? If I want to access the path for my directory, but I can not though i'm pretty sure im making a mistake on the same line.

```
string directoryPath = args[0];
```

This is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                string directoryPath = args[0];
                string[] filesList, filesListTmp;
                IFileOperation[] opList = { new FileProcNameAfter10(),
                                            new FileProcEnc(),
                                            new FileProcByExt("jpeg"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("jpg"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("doc"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("pdf"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("djvu")
                                            };
                if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                {
                    filesList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        filesListTmp = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
                        foreach (var elem in Enumerable.Except<string>(filesListTmp, filesList))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(elem);
                            foreach (var op in opList)
                            {
                                if (op.Accept(elem)) op.Process(elem);
                            }
                        }
                        filesList = filesListTmp;
                        if (Console.KeyAvailable == true && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is no such directory.");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Whatever you pass to it

Comment: if you are not giving any arguments to the program, no arguments will be stored

Answer (score 3):

> what does args 0 store in this program

Its [command line parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you get value in it if you execute your `exe` from command line with parameters.

For debugging purpose you can send it through visual studio as well, go to project properties, Debug and under start option specify.

[image]

Comment: Not just through command line. If you drag a file/folder onto the .exe the first arg will be the path.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, and that's because the Windows shell passes the path as a ***command-line*** parameter.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so `args[0]` represents the first command-line parameter passed to the program - so in short we have no idea what it represents in your case. But consider this command-line:

```
MyProgram.exe
```

that would pass nothing into the `args[]` and therefore there wouldn't be any index of `0`. Now consider this command-line:

```
MyProgram.exe Hello
```

that would pass `Hello` into the `args[]` and therefore the value at index `0` would be `Hello`. Now let's consider this command-line:

```
MyProgram.exe Hello World
```

that would pass `Hello` and `World` into the `args[]` and therefore the value at index `0` would be `Hello` and the value at index `1` would be `World`. Now, another thing to remember is to `"` parameters, especially when necessarily dealing with paths:

```
MyProgram.exe "C:\MyPath\ToSomewhere"
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I want to access the path for my Directory [...]

If you want to get the Location of your application, you can try

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

See this question as well: [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/837488)

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the command line parameter to something so that the `arg[0]` is populated with something. You can do this from the Debug tab of your project properties and setting the Command Line Arguments field. This will allow you to debug your application as if a command line was specified from the prompt when run outside of the IDE. Generally you should always check for the existence of a parameter before you try using it like;

```
if (args != null && args.Length > 1)
{
    // now you know there's thing in "args[0]"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`args[0]` contains the first commandline parameter passed when starting your application.

Answer (score 1):

args[0] is the first argument passed during execution i.e.

> C:\Path to your program\Program.exe "Your directory path"