# How can I make a program finds it&#39;s own location to save and read a file?

Tags: c#, error-handling, permissions

I'm trying to write an xml file and attach it to an email. It works great if I give it a path to my personal documents folder(i.e. `C:\users\myname\Documents\Test.xml`), but if I try to change it to something like `C:\\Test.xml`, I get the following error message:

> *UnauthorizedAccessException was Unhandled Access to the path
>   'C:\Test.xml' is denied.*

(I can't post pictures apparently)

What would be a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the directory in which the application is launched you could use [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)

**On Admin privileges:**

1. Check if the user has launched the application using `Run as Administrator`.
   In this case user should have admin privileges to write..Here is sample code..

   ```
       var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
       var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
       if (principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
       {
           //Application is Running as ADMIN
       }
   ```
2. You could always write it to you `TEMP` or `LOCAL APP DATA` folder..

   ```
       var temp = Path.GetTempPath();

       //e.g: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\test.xml
       var testFilePath = Path.Combine(temp, "test.xml");
   ```

Comment: Sorry, but what namespace do I need to use to get Path.GetTempPath();?

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(‌​).CodeBase)

see [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app)

Comment: Also, if you have UAC enabled, you can't write to the C drive without admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Program folder is not always allowed to write, use %TEMP% folder instead.