# Application doesnt exist in C# console and I want to restart the console

Tags: c#

I have made a hangman game, and I want to be able to restart it after you've won/lost, rather than having to restart the program manually every time.

I saw on the internet 'Application' which can be used to restart the console. However, it says that Application doesnt exist.

```
 Close();
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Please help me!

Comment: Can't you just add some code to reset application instead of actually restarting it?

Comment: I guess you heard about loops and stuff? Is there a valid reason why you need to *restart* the program?

Comment: See Patrick's answer on how to get the executing / entry assembly but as JLe says this is not a great solution to your actual problem. I.e. you should not have to restart the game each time.

Consider having a method that resets your state to a know state or encapsulating your state in a separate object etc

Answer (score 1):

You can find it over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

You need to include the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and add a `using`

```
using System.Windows.Forms
```

But for Console apps I would prefer to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application) (when in your Console assembly):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Like Andre said as comment, you'd even better use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` since it gets the first assembly that is called (which is of course the executable in console applications)

And of couse, like the previous answer which is removed already, first reopen, and then close the application.

Comment: I agree. Definitely don't add a dependency on winforms just to get the assembly path. Also take a look at Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()

Comment: okay, I tried adding the using System.Windows.Forms, and I got the error 'The type or namespace name 'Windows' doesnt exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: @FatPoo2: and the assembly? Did you add it?

Comment: where do I add the assembly?

Comment: Where is the add reference box?

Comment: Please read the documentation under section "To add a reference in Visual C#"

Comment: ok, that bits working now. not too sure about the System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Comment: @FatPoo2: that is an alternative that is more advanced, but if this works for you, don't care about it.

Comment: @FatPoo2: glad to help you. Since you are new, don't forget to mark the question as answered if you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need to restart your console application to restart your game. Here is a possible game restarting scenario which can be used:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game game = new Game();

        Menu menu = new Menu(game);

        game.Finished += menu.AskAndRun;

        menu.Welcome();
    }
}

class Menu
{
    public readonly IRunnable runnable;

    public Menu(IRunnable runnable)
    {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    public void Welcome()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome, Player!");

        AskAndRun();
    }

    public void AskAndRun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nTo play a new game, press [ENTER]");

        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Clear();

        runnable.Run();
    }
}

interface IRunnable
{
    void Run();
}

class Game : IRunnable
{
    public event Action Finished;

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Game started here...");

        Console.WriteLine("Oops! Game finished already");

        if (Finished != null)
        {
            Finished();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Game` class was separated from the restarting logic which now handled by `Menu` class. Now it is trivial to introduce new features like exiting and counting number of started games.

Pay attention to the fact that `Menu` doesn't depend on `Game`. It depends on `IRunnable` and this will help you in changing the `Game`, testing `Menu` and introducing new features painlessly.