# Get application directory in both console application and its unit tests

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper, console-application, shadow-copy

I have a console application project with NUnit tests in the same project.

I have been trying to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837501/3421814).

At run-time the solution worked OK. But when I ran the tests by Resharper test runner or NUnit GUI runner, `GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returned a path like this: `d:\Temp\f4ctjcmr.ofr\nojeuppd.fmf\R2Nbs\assembly\dl3\9766f38e\b9496fb3_43cccf01\`.
Disabling shadow-copying fixed the problem in both test runners, but new problems appeared (VS is not able to build the project until NUnit Gui is closed). Is there a better solution than disabling shadow-copying?

**Update:** `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` returned `C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\` in the tests running in NUnit Gui with shadow-copying enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147792/3421814) solution worked for me. Please vote to its author if it helps you.

As explained in the MSDN forums post, [How to convert URI path to normal filepath?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/csharplanguage/thread/9341a48b-5c23-4b54-a354-2e21732cbea5), I used the following:

```
// Get normal filepath of this assembly's permanent directory
var path = new Uri(
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
    ).LocalPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this goes into fun territory.

**You should be mocking out this dependency.**

Example code:

```
public interface IApplicationRootService {
    Uri GetApplicationRoot();
}

public class ApplicationRootService : IApplicationRootService {
    public Uri GetApplicationRoot() {
        //etc
    }
}
```

Now, apply liberally to your code where you're calling getexecutingassembly and whatnot. Inject the IApplicationRootService as a constructor dependency.

Ex:

```
public class DoWork {
    private IApplicationRootService _applicationRootService;
    public DoWork(IApplicationRootService applicationRootService) {
        _applicationRootService = applicationRootService;
    }
    public void DoSomething() {
        var appRoot = _applicationRooService.GetApplicationRoot();
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Now when you're testing, use a mocking service and mock out the return value of application root to the appropriate folder for nunit to go sniffin'.

Ex code, using nunit and moq:

```
[Test]
public static void test_do_something() {
    var applicationRootService = new Mock<IApplicationRootService>();
    applicationRootService.Setup(service => service.GetApplicationRoot()).Returns(new Uri("MyRoot", UriKind.Relative);
    var myClass = new DoWork(applicationRootService.Object);
    //continue testing!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will probably do this if I do not have a better option.