# How to get setup.exe folder path for ClickOnce

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have a click once Application which is deployed in folder say, "c:\temp\MyApp". In this folder I have a config file "MyAppDynamic.config" which I want my click once app to read when it starts.

When I click on c:\temp\MyApp\setup.exe, ClickOnce App is deployed in %APPDATA%.. folder and hence I am not able to get the folder location from where clickonce is launched.

1. Is there a way to get the launch location in clickonce app?
2. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

RDV

Little more info:

My clickonce app's main purpose is to install a bunch of pre-reqs on client box. These pre-reqs can be located anywhere on network (their location changes depending upon whether the particular component is in development or production). I did not want to update the clickonce installer just because some dynamic location changed and thats why I do not want to hardcode the installation paths in ClickOnce app.

Hence, I am using an external file "MyAppDynamic.config" where I update the installation paths of all components and I place this file in the published folder where setup.exe resides.

The problem is I want to read this file when ClickOnce application starts, but any System/Environment variable wont give me this published location because by this time, ClickOnce is already deployed on Client Box and all Location/CodeBase paths point to %APPDATA%..

**Question:**

1. Is it possible for a deployed clickonce application to get its installation directory path (I verified IsolatedStorage does not provide this information)?
2. Is above not not possible, are there any ideas how to achieve this? Again I do not even want to hardcode location of MyAppDynmaic.config file. But if nothing else work, this is going to be my best bet :-(

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get or set location of installation. Installation folder is under Isolated Storage for security purpose. You can read your config file. Check this answer;

[How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)

Comment: Thanks Omaer. Alas.. this doesn't help either. I have updated my problem statement to explain the situation further.

Comment: sorry, there is no way to do this. i tried to explain why is not possible.

Comment: can you try the wix toolset? its is solid and the powerful.