# Crystal reports dynamic logo(image)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am using visual studio 2010 and trying to add a dynamic image into the crystal report, i dont want to use dataset, how could i assign a URL to the image, and just change the image with the same name (ex: c:\logo.jpg different image than the existing one but the same name) and the report read it.

thanks for your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing anything make new parameter (string) which will be presenting your URL of your image.

Then insert picture in your **Crystal Report** (1)(choose some default picture, blank or whatever picture). Next `right click` on picture and `Format Graphics` (2). Go to section `Picture` (3) and write down formula for URL.

Picture of step 1, 2 and 3.

[image: Setup]

Simple and easy

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the help !

i need that the path will be my application path -

 Application.StartupPath + @"\MyPic.jpg";

how to do it ?  can i get a sampe ?

thanks

Comment: You save that report in your `img` folder. And if you want to show `cat.jpg` just forward your parameter that string. Remember, location of the report must be the same where are images.

Comment: no, it works in A predetermined path, but i need to change the path in my program Dynamic. how to do it ?  thanks

Comment: For that problem check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)