# How to show/display images dynamically from SQL Database to Crystal Report 7?

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

> EDIT: I've already asked this also in SAP and I already have an
>   answer regarding my concern. Please see it in Answer section below.

I would like to ask for help in how can I display the image in Crystal Report 7 details section from image (byte) database field? As I've tried to place the image in details section, there's no image shown in design/run mode. I've tried to include another database field to make sure there are records retrieve and as per testing, the other details (like imgID & imgName) were displayed.

I've been searching for solution to this for several weeks but I still cannot find any answers. I'm hoping someone could help me solve this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considering about saving images to some directory and display then images depending on a path of images? Similar problem solved already in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985509/crystal-reports-dynamic-logoimage/31987448#31987448)

Comment: Hi @KuKeC , already saw the same scenario from your link but Crystal Report 7 does not have the `Graphic Location` part and the `Formula Editor for URL` as well. Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Crystal Reports were handled by SAP, I've also posted my question in SAP Community Network.

BLOB fields (in Crystal Report 7) are no longer supported by MSSQL 2012 (the database I am using).

You can view it the full thread here... http://scn.sap.com/message/16233263#16233263

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so did you tried some other approach for the same?