# C# - Viewing Image In Crystal Report Using File Path

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm done creating "take a photo and save photo" using C#. The saving process is when the user submits the data, the savefiledialog will trigger to response. Then it will save on the coded path

```
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\Users\\image-path\\";
```

Then the column value that will be inserted on the table is only "Varchar" and the "Path" value which is the

```
tblcolumnpath = C:\Users\image-path\myimage.jpg;
```

I can now view it using PictureBox Tool in a regular window form. My problem is, I don't know how can I view it using Crystal Report form. Crystal Report has no "PictureBox" in its toolbox. Any help, please comment or answer it. Thank you in advance. I'm just 2 Months old in using C#.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985509/crystal-reports-dynamic-logoimage/). Hope it helps

Comment: sir @KuKeC please put your comment on "Add Answer" :) This is help me a lot. :) I'll  mark it as "Answered"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar problem was solved already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985509/crystal-reports-dynamic-logoimage). If you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you sir! God bless :D Amen... +

Comment: No problem, next time try to search some similar questions and answers  before and then ask if you don't find answer. :)

Comment: Sure sir... Thank you again.