# How i can show the image using Crystal report?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, crystal-reports

How can i show image from hard disk or drive using crystal report. I'm using visual studio 2010, i'm not save and retrive the images from database.

When i have load the report its search the images from particular folder then select images and display the report.

Now I insert the picture from Crystal report but it's not changing the images from runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To show dynamical image from your `C#` code to report you need to put image in your desired section, and let that image be whatever image on your hard drive. After that you change location URL of that image in options of that image. I already answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31987448/5139222) so check that for more information/help.

Hope it helps