# How Can i display a dynamic image in crystal report using java

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am trying to use a dynamic image in a crystal report using java class.
I tried to put an image path on the URI properties of the image, but i doesn't work. Another idea to make a dynamic image? The version of the crystal is 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with dynamic images should be done by manipulating uri of some field (can be text) and then change uri of picture regarding of that field. For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31987448/5139222)

Hope it helps