# C#: How to give internal project path in the code?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a console application using Selenium web driver c# and I have a folder in my project which contains the Chromedriver.exe. I want to give the path of that folder in my file. What should I do for this?

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\sharmaash\Documents\Software\chromedriver_win32")
```

I am using this in my code, what changes I need to make in the above mentioned code line?

The screenshot of my local folder which I need to access:
[image]

I want to give a path of chromedriver.exe in:
`IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\sharmaash\Documents\Software\chromedriver_win32")` rightnow I am using my local system path. The reason behind is I want to create an exe file of my application and for that I want to give relative path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)

Comment: Thanks, I have made some changes in my question. Can you please suggest on it.

Comment: can you put your folder structure and where this driver is put so we can help u ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using NuGet to manage dependencies. It will automatically copy the chromedriver.exe to output folder. 
[image: NuGet install chromedriver]

Another solution is to add the chromedriver.exe to project then set property "Copy to Output Directory" as Copy if Newer.
[image: Add chromedriver.exe to project]

[image: Set value to Copy if Newer]

Then you can create ChromeDriver by:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Then you can use the second solution which is adding the chromedriver.exe to project then set property "Copy to Output Directory" as Copy if Newer.

Comment: I do it like this, too (the 2nd solution). Works perfectly fine. No need to specify the path when instantiating the ChromeDriver, as it is in the same path as your compiled binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the path in a config file instead of hard coding it and fetch it from there. Secondly you can get path of your application code base, where your application code resides by using following statement and provide it to your ChromeDriver Constructor

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase

Dynamic Path Get
e.g.

string driverPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath);

Comment: I just placed this code on my file: `string driverPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase; IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath);` Now where should I add the "\chromedriver_win32" path?

Comment: can you put your folder structure and where this driver is put so we can help u ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshot. Please suggest