# How do I link a specific file in c#?

Tags: c#, file

I have a program that can edit a certain text file. Currently, I am only running it in Visual Studios. When I am referring to the text file, the file path looks something like this:

> @"C:\myProjectFolder\someTextFile.txt"

For now, I can use this path and it works flawlessly, but after I deploy it, the program would only work on my computer because this path is specific to my computer.

In HTML for example, if I was linking a CSS file, it would be possible to do `\stylesheets\style.css` instead of `C:\myWebsite\stylesheets\style.css`

How can I achieve something similar in C#

Comment: You can get the Executable directory, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application

Comment: Lookup A File OpenDialog, then user can pick a file.

Comment: @PoulBak I have considered that but I don't want to have to have the user specify a file.

Comment: Use a system defined path like `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`

Comment: Use paths relative to the app dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath and Application.executablePath`for getting  current application path.
if file is in current directory of `.Exe` file full path is not required and just name of file is enough. you also can point to current path in some situations by `".\\"`