# How do I get the application path of an addin host executable?

Tags: c#, add-in

How do I get the application path of an addin host executable? Using varying methods, I can get the path of my assembly. This is not what I want. I am working on an addon and I need to get the path of the main application executable path. I have researched  at the VS Gallery, Stack Overflow, and google. Surprisingly, there are absolutely no questions regarding this topic.

To clarify the question - I have an executable application in some unknown path (we are to assume the path is unknown) that implements an addin (somessembly.dll) at the assembly path. Here we need to get the unknown path of the executable application.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application

Comment: What about string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location?