# How to Start and Kill a process from a windows service

Tags: windows-services

I am trying to Start and Kill my wpf application from a windows service.Here what I used to start the application :

```
Process.Start("MyApplicationName");
```

It gives me the following exception here :

```
> The system cannot find the file specified;;   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
```

And while killing the process it gives me the following exception

```
> The system cannot find the file specified;;   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at SSMScoreboardService.Service1.Scoreboard(String status)
```

While the same piece of code works perfectly with Winform application.

Comment: The exception you are getting can be due to insufficient privileges. Is your target process designed to run in the services context?

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced No, How to do that? And regarding privileges same thing is running perfectly in winform application

Comment: Are you providing the full path to the executable file?

Comment: @HarryJohnston NO, But I'd kept it on my working directory

Answer (score 0):

The current (or "working") directory is a legacy concept, useful for simple command-line tools but otherwise best avoided.

In this particular case, it looks like your problem is that services are always started with the current directory set to `c:\windows\system32` whereas you appear to be assuming that the current directory will be set to the directory containing the service executable, as would happen when a normal application is run from Explorer.

Your code should explicitly locate the directory containing the service executable and use that to build the path to the child executable.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/837488/886887) for more information.

If the child executable also assumes that the current directory is going to be the same as the application directory, you can use `Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to select the current directory that will be assigned to the child.