# Associated File type does not return the file location

Tags: c#

I have set my  Associated file settings in the publish settings, when I click on my file it opens the program but it does not pass the args. So I can't do anything with the file. I think that is have set it up properly I have added a string argument to the main but its always blank.

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string[] openvalue = new string[1];
        //thingoo = new string[0];
        //thingoo[0] = "hi therer hows it...";

        try
        {
            if (args[0] != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm(args));
    }
}
```

args[0] should be the file location but its blank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason unknown to mankind, this is the answer...

string[] activationData = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;

It is string 0 in this array, If someone can point to the documentation to this that would be great I'm not sure how its related of why its there but a random post on the internet revealed this after about 20 hours of looking...

Comment: They changed it from c++ in c#. command line arguments do no longer include the file path of the executable. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)