# In .NET console app, how to get the path of the command prompt where the user typed the command?

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

I created the following .NET console app, built it, and copied the executable `deepdir.exe` to `c:\commandlineapps` and then set an enviroment variable to this directory so that I can call this command from any directory.

How do I get the directory from where the user typed the command, e.g. `c:\docs\project1`, and NOT the directory where the .exe file exists, e.g. `c:\commandlineapps`? None of the following work:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace showimages
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var docPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            docPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            docPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
            docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            docPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            docPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            docPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            docPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            docPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
            docPath = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;
            docPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            Console.WriteLine(docPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Application.StartupPath?

Comment: @SteveTodd What namespace is that? In my C# console application, I get the error "The name `Application` does not exist in the current context." The only namespace it offers is `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames` which doesn't have `StartupPath`.

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`?

Comment: @steve16351 When I use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, it gives me `C:\WINDOWS`.

Comment: See [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)

Comment: Sorry, Application is part of WinForms. Does Environment.CommandLine give you anything useful?

Comment: @RobertBaron As advised in the selected answer on that post, I tried `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` but it gives me `c:\commandlineapps` and not `c:\docs\project1` which is where I typed the command. The last comment on the selected answer notes rightly, "I do not understand at all why this is marked as the correct answer. It does not work in all the scenarios."

Comment: @SteveTodd `Environment.CommandLine` simply gives me `deepdir` or if I type in an argument e.g. `deepdir *.png`, then it returns `deepdir *.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.8) will do what you need (get the current working directory).

Comment: Typing `Environment.GetCurrentDirectory()` tells me that `Environment` does not contain `GetCurrentDirectory`. And `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns `C:\WINDOWS` regardless of where I execute my command.

Comment: Why `Environment`? Use `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` works, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.