# How do I get local database work on my client’s PC

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, localdb

I’ve built an application with a local .mdf database, and I’ve deployed the app. I tested it on my PC; there were no problems. The application works perfectly. Today, I installed the app on a client’s PC, and I got this error:

[image]

Although all the files are in place and SQL Server 2016 installed on my client’s PC.

Comment: Did you at least do what message says?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Share your code, exception detail and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You need to install [localdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) on client's machine. The error message says that the localdb is not installed or the service is not running.

Comment: If I remember right, data tools options on the Visual Studio installation will add local DB to the computer. Was that option chosen upon installation?

Comment: @AntoineHernandez I’ve checked the box saying, SQL Server 2012 LocalDB and the 2012 one was the only option available.

Comment: I got the option wrong, it was Data Storage and Processing. That installs the SQL Server Data Tools components, which includes a localized SQL Server instance. Regardless of that, check the connection string in the application to make sure it’s pointed to the proper location.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons:

1. You either used a fixed source path like:

```
c:\MyProgram\database.mdf
```

So if you move the database somewhere else other than that folder, simply it won't work because it won't be able to find Database file.

[Solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application) use a dynamic location, so no matter where the app is installed, it should find your DB.

2. the installed SQL Server **is not the same version** or higher as your DB, or not installed properly.

[Solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950156/where-to-download-sql-server-2016-express-localdb-offline-installer) reinstall or repair [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56840).

Comment: I’ve used |DataDirectory|\DB.mdf

Comment: His SQL Server is exactly 2016.

Comment: You maybe need the other version of SQL Server 2016. And was the DB located in your bin folder or just outside; I mean you are sure that it has moved along with your app.