# how to get the path in a .NET console application

Tags: c#, console-application

For example I have a console application named "myconsole.exe" which path is C:\temp\app\myconsole.exe
I added "C:\temp\app" to the PATH environment variable, Now I open the command prompt, type `CD C:\MyProjects` and run `myconsole`, how can I get the path "C:\MyProjects" in myconsole.exe?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netcore-3.1) method is what you are looking for.