# How to access files copied to output directory with CopyToOutputDirectory in ASP NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have an ASP NET Core 6 API application hosted on Azure App Service.
Together with the application we would like to deploy some external xml files that are used later on by the backend runtime. We have added them to the project and set `CopyToOutputDirectory = true`.

Have to questions:

1. How to access these files from code in safe way?
   What we tried is

- `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)?.Substring(6)` to get base path but it looks hacky.
- `_webHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` but it returns wrong location in development (project root folder instead of /bin)
- using relative path `Path.GetFullName("file.xml")` but it returns project root folder in development as well

2. We saw that there is another property that can be set on file called `CopyToPublishDirectory`. When it should be set? We set only `CopyToOutputDirectory` and it seems to work also when doing dotnet publish. Any reference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)

Comment: When deploying a project the files need to be in same folder as the executable just like they are in the bin folder of the project.  So you do not need to use the folder name to access the files.

Comment: @gunr2171, no it doesn't. I am asking about ASP NET Core application hosted on azure, your question is about console app.

Comment: I'm not sure how "being on Azure" makes a difference. Why the Substring(6)? If you're setting the Working Directory (or it's already set the the application's binaries directory), then a relative path can work as jdweng said.

Comment: @gunr2171 when using relative path, it doesn't work locally (in development). Path.GetFullPath("file.xml") returns project root folder locally instead of /bin where files are copied to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's approach this problem in a different way. When we publish the project, we include the `bin` folder in the publish file. Then you can access `.xml` inside the `bin` folder.

1. Show all files and include to your project.

   [image: show all file]

   [image: Include bin folder]
2. Open .csproj file and modify it.

   [image: Include bin folder]

   And your csproj file should be like:

   https://dotnetfiddle.net/qG3W8h

   comment out this paragraph and add CopyToOutputDirectory, like below:

   https://dotnetfiddle.net/jrccnJ
3. Then you can deploy it, then you can find the bin folder.

   [image: Include bin folder]
4. Then you can access the file gracefully.