# how to get the installation path in C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I am modifying a .NET v4.5.2 code, and I want to be able to get a script path from the installation folder (so when a user install the app, the app is able to access and run the script)

I tried `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` method but it returned the wrong value (it returned the path: "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming" , whereas my program location (after installation) is "C:\Program Files (x86)". I also tried `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` and `Path.GetDirectoryName(appFileName)` but they returned the location of the file where the code was written. could you please help me?

Comment: It is worth noting that .net 4.5.2 is End Of Life, as of April 2022. You should strongly consider upgrading.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application

Answer (score 1):

try [AppDomain.BaseDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=net-7.0)

```
String _path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Comment: I have my doubts that this would result in something much different from `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]`.

Comment: Thank you ..I have just tried it, it also returns the code file location