C# Console application delete folder with file path problem
hey guys i'm getting desperate about my little application which is why i'm asking for advice here now
the point is that my application should empty a folder but i don't want to specify C:\USERNAME in the source but the consone should use the startpath of the debug folder do you understand?
I would like to change what I have marked in bold so that it works on every pc and not just on my pc
my code that also works but I don't want to have the whole path:
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.Title = ("Cachecleaner");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            **DirectoryInfo Cache = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\BA55H4XQR\\source\\repos\\CacheWeb\\CacheWeb\\bin\\Debug\\Cache\\EBWebView");**
            
            
            foreach (FileInfo files in Cache.GetFiles()) 
            { 
                files.Delete();
                Console.WriteLine("Files Deleted");

            }
            foreach(DirectoryInfo folders in Cache.GetDirectories())
            {
                folders.Delete(true);
                Console.WriteLine("Folders Deleted");
            }

DirectoryInfo Cache = new DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\BA55H4XQR\source\repos\CacheWeb\CacheWeb\bin\Debug\Cache\EBWebView");

EBWebView is created by WebView2. The following may be of interest: Clear browsing data from the user data folder

Seems like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application to me

I'm assuming your program us running in the debug folder in your path. You can get the assembly that represents your application Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly. Once you have that, you can get its folder Assembly.Location. Finally use Path.Combine to build your path (if I'm following correctly)
