# Temp ASP.NET Files

Tags: asp.net

I have almost 800 MB and over 31,000 files in hundreds of subfolders at the following file location:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\temporary asp.net files

Are files truly temporary and are they ever cleaned up? Can they be safely deleted, perhaps, after stopping IIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can be safely deleted after stopping IIS and they will regenerate what is needed when a user accesses your site.

-Shaun

Comment: Are they ever automatically cleaned up? I imagine it took a while to accumulate 800 MB worth of files. I'm a little chicken to remove them even though I would tend to also think it is safe.

Comment: They are not automatically cleaned up but if they are growing too large I would have a scheduled task execute upon recycle of your IIS process to clean them up for you.

Answer (score 7):

They aren't "temporary" in the literal sense of the word that they will definitely be removed at some point. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450831/what-is-the-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-for) describes the purpose pretty well:

> These are what's known as Shadow Copy Folders.
>
> Simplistically....and I really mean it:
>
> When ASP.NET runs your app for the first time, it copies any assemblies found in the /bin folder, copies any source code files (found for example in the App_Code folder) and parses your aspx, ascx files to c# source files. ASP.NET then builds/compiles all this code into a runnable application.

They can be deleted at any time, and .NET will just recreate the ones it needs, when it needs them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can safely delete them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just about certain that orphaned (i.e. that don't correspond to virtual directory anymore) temp files are never cleaned up.