# How can I change a single aspx page from hosted published website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have made some edits in my aspx code behind cs file. I can't make the site down since our site will miss our viewers.I want to make the update possible with this single page upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for strategies of seamless deployment for IIS asp.net apps; this can be achieved via two machines and a load-balancer before them - [Seamless deployment in ASP.NET (IIS kills worker process before new worker process is ready)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358020/seamless-deployment-in-asp-net-iis-kills-worker-process-before-new-worker-proce?lq=1)

Another convoluted way is to host two identical websites on the same host and switch between them, as explained - [Is smooth deployment possible with componentized ASP.NET MVC apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521208/is-smooth-deployment-possible-with-componentized-asp-net-mvc-apps#4526754)

Comment: I want to change a single aspx page from my published site

Comment: you can't do that without affecting live users who are using the aspx.