# Question On Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

Have a question on "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder; I have bit knowledge on what this folder is for as outlined by another thread in this forum

[What is the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450831/what-is-the-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-for)

But recently, I am getting a warning while trying to build my new project as below

'c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\some folder\filename.cs' conflicts with the imported type ... using the one ...

Looks like that, two copy (shadow copy) of the same class (.cs file) file exist in two different version of temp folder and hence it's confusing as to use which one.

My Question is: Shall I go ahead and delete all contents from "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder? Is there any side affect if I do so? Please let me know.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you close all of your instances of VS 2005, you can delete all of the files/folders within this folder. This folder is exactly as it's named -- Temporary. It loads all of the instances of your compiled files as they enter memory when they're loaded for a website. When you perform a "clean" on your solution it is supposed to empty the files in the folder relating to your open solution.

If you empty out your files and you continue to have this problem, then the problem will be related to how you have referenced projects and third party libraries within your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you take now your project, put it in a zip and send it to a friend, than he doesnt have the temporary folder for that project, and can build it too... So your main stuff should be in the project directory itself. Have you everything saved properly? Than close your Vs and clean the mess. (99% sure)

Comment: Nope I am still doing my stuff and haven't saved the updates. I was thinkiing the same ... that once I am done ... I will close my project and VS; then will go ahead and delete all the files OR everything under "asp.net temp files" folder but was not sure whether it's safe or not. From, your comment looks like it's safe and no harm will cause (I know the same compiled files will be recreated and running the project will be bit slow ... but that's a don't care condition for me). Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Clean your solution/project and recompile?  That would only remove the compiled/temporary files associated with that project.