# dlls copied to some strage location under iis7

Tags: .net, web-services, iis-7, iis-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “Temporary ASP.NET Files” folder for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450831/what-is-the-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-for)

I have some web-service that been upgraded from iis6 to iis7 and to application pool .net 4.0.
Under iis6 everything was working OK.

On start up of the webservice under  application pool .net 4.0 , one of the startup binary is copied to

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\RTService\b19c4d8f\16493894\assembly\dl3
```

but the start up binary has dependency to some xml file that is not copied .
But it presented under normal deployment directory.

Any idea what is this directory and why my dll is running from there and how i can solve my issues.

Answer (score 0):

If the application uses dynamic complilation the assembly will be compiled to this location, which is commonly referred to as a shadow copy folder.

> When ASP.NET runs your app for the first time, it copies any assemblies found in the /bin folder, copies any source code files (found for example in the App_Code folder) and parses your aspx, ascx files to c# source files. ASP.NET then builds/compiles all this code into a runnable application.

This is pretty normal though, and it shouldn't give you any trouble. If it is giving you problems, try clearing the contents and deploy your application again. If it's still giving you problems, I would consider using precompilation.

Comment: my application not working at all because of it. under application pool of .net it works but after migration to .net 4.0 and iis7 problem started

Comment: Because that directory is only for assemblies. Since your code is compiled on the fly and does not generate an assembly in the `bin` folder, it has to put the compiled assembly somewhere.