# Are Dynamically Compiled Assemblies for .ASPX files in Server Memory?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I've read that dynamically compiled assemblies and other resources for .aspx pages are stored in:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[VERSION]\Temporary ASP.NET Files

or 

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[VERSION]\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

I am unable to find any files there other than one hash directory and 1 .web file. I can view the pages, however. When I explicitly dump the files to a directory via the web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" tempDirectory="c:\temp\" />
```

**only then** do I see the files (.dll's, .cmdline's, .compiled, etc).

So my question is, where are the files if I don't have that line in my web.config? Are they stored in memory after they've been dynamically compiled or compiled before deploying?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the project in IIS or Visual Studio?

Comment: Is this a web project or web site?

Comment: See if this explains it for you: [What is the temporary asp net files folder for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450831/what-is-the-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-for),

Comment: Jeff: Visual Studio 2010. 

Oded: I've tried both.

Comment: DOK: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't explain what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path to one of generated assemblies can be like that 
C:\Users\{User_Name}\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5fba2019\f07d83d6\assembly\dl3\58fc15e5\135e9dc1_40b4cc01\WebApplication1.DLL

So, all autogenerated files storing here C:\Users\{User_Name}\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Comment: Awesome, there they are. Thanks. I wonder why it wasn't mentioned in a lot of articles/posts I read.