# ASP.NET app stopps working when disk is full

Tags: asp.net, iis

This is a bit wierd question but:

We have a ASP.NET webapplication (4.0) that runs on a iis 7.5.
Because of logging, the disk sometimes gets full and the application stops working. Since the disk is full, we don't get a log message for why the application stops working. The iis-logs are written to a folder within inetpub and the application is placed withing inetpub aswell.

1. What could some typical reasons for an ASP.NET App to stop working be when the disk is full?
2. How do people usualy set up their servers so that overflowing logs does not take down the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About second question: we always setup logs on different drive, which are easy to manage, more secure (asp.net does not have right to write to application folder)

About first one: you have warnings in event log when your disk are almost full, full, etc. You can setup it easy in Windows Server

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET can create temporary files of your pages etc so it's probably that that's failing (see this previous SO - [What is the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450831/what-is-the-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-for)).

We usually have large disks. If space is at a premium we also turn on folder compression for the log directories and ultimately we have a scheduled cleanup task that will nuke older files. However the caveat here is if you cleaned up once a week it still means if you have tons of logs generated within that time frame the disk would still fill up.

In an ideal world you'd probably ship your logs off somewhere else for processing and archiving.