# Use a file in a c# application

Tags: c#

I'd like to add a `config.json` file to my project and have a class read from the file.

I added the file in VS and added the `Build Action` = `Content` and `Copy to output directory` = `Copy always` properties.

When building, the file is copied to `C:\...\mysolution\myproject\bin\Debug`.

But `File.ReadAllText(@"config.json")` throws a `FileNotFoundException`.
`Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);` doesn't return the folder where the file is copied:
`C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\2158bea8\\d46fc01c\\assembly\\dl3\\eca14761\\49a747bf_be72d001`

Comment: what is the type of this solution (web - console)?

Comment: @MohammedElSayed How can I find out? It doesn't open a console. My startup project is a nancyfx server running on IIS Express.

Comment: nancy can be selfhosted or iis hosted, there is nothing called nancyserver on IIS, :)  if IIS MUST be running in order to get a result, then it's hosted on IIS.

Answer (score 2):

"\config.json" will read from ROOT, try "config.json"

Comment: This throws the same exception. (Updated question)

Comment: so, the CLASS has the output file? you need to make sure its in the WORKING folder of the Application. Or if its ASP.NET which it looks like it is then the web root.

Comment: it will not end up in

C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\2158bea8\\d46fc01c\\assembly\\dl3\\eca14761\\49a747bf_be72d001 (run time build)

As its the BUILD of the WEB SITE that is putting the file in that folder.

Comment: This covers what the TEMP ASP.NET files are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450831/what-is-the-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-for

Comment: The linked answer says that this temp folder doesn't need any maintainance. How can I get VS to copy the files into that folder? @Steve Drake

Comment: Make the config.json part of the ASP.NET project. I am sure someone suggested that earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure if my solution has an ASP.NET project. (Is NancyFX ASP.NET?). However, my project is not the server project and I want it to be used by different servers. The config file shoulld only be for this project (not the entire solution). I'm looking for a way to have a config file for just the project.

Answer (score 0):

as Steve said, you need to use "config.json", this will read from where the exe or application resides.

So you need to tell VS to copy this file to your output directory when building, to this do the following:

Right click the file in VS > Properties > Set "Copy to output Directory" to "Copy Always"

Comment: I did do that, still getting the exception.