# Get execution path of class project used in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, flash, iis

I'm working in a legacy project that still using flash as front end.

But the backend is in c# .net 3.5.

I've created a new functionality that needs a file of the application, to do this I've used:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location)
```

But it's showing that error:

> 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\sirius2\af2e88a7\10f74a24\assembly\dl3\872c826f\89d0f861_6ef5d001\Images'
>   is denied

The project use IIS and the right path, the path where we can find the folder Images is in the directory mapped in IIS.

Is there a way to obtain that path?

Answer (score 5):

Some answers are using a web project. But I'm using a Class Project, and Server class is not referenced in that kind of project.

Really is a problem created by shadow copy of dlls, but to resolve I need to use

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.ToString()).LocalPath)
```

And it returns the real path of dll.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: The best and correct solution for web environment to locate bin folder

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way asp.net handles your compiled code (by using Shadow Copy folders  - the "Temporary ASP>NET Files dir" from above - you cannot use the regular Path.XXX static methods (see [What is the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450831/what-is-the-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-for) for a fuller answer).

Instead you can use 
`Server.MapPath("/")` 
which will return the physical path of the root of the app - so you can also do (for example) Server.MapPath("/Images").

This answer shows other options for MapPath:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/275791/990323

---

For clarity (from the comments below):
`"/"` will return a path relative to the root of the domain (i.e. `"C:\inetpub\wwwroot"`. `"~/"` returns the path relative to where the application is actually installed `"C/MyCode/MyWebApp"` Only by not beginning the string with a forward/backslash or tilde to you get relative path behaviour as discussed below.

Comment: My understanding was `MapPAth("/")` was the web site root which may be suitable for the OP.  The OP did not specify how the site was set up (i..e application under the site etc) so I linked to another answer with more options.  I don't see how the post was particularly unhelpful..

Comment: No - this is incorrect.  The difference between "/" and "~/" is not related to the request.  See the full answer by @splattne  in the link.

Comment: For clarity:
"/" will return a path relative to the root of the domain (i.e. "C:|inetpub\wwwroot".

"~/" returns the path relative to where the application is actually installed "C/MyCode/MyWebApp"

Only by not beginning the string with a forward/backslash or tilde to you get the relative behaviour you are talking about.

Comment: can you do a quick edit and I will remove the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static directory you are trying to access, typically you'll want to specify directories relative to the application root.  This is done using "~/".  For example, if you always wanted to find the physical directory for http://myapplication/images regardless of the directory your request is executing in, then you'd use the following:

```
string rootImageDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/Images");
```

If you don't specify the tilde and just use "/", then the directory returned is relative to the current execution path instead of to the root of the application.