# Kentico imports custom namespace, can't identify the assembly

Tags: namespaces, custom-controls, kentico

Looking at a Kentico 7 custom module (ascx) that references a namespace (e.g.:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyCustom.Things" %>
```

I looked in the \bin directory for the site itself and can't find any reference to MyCustom.Things. I tried **ildasm** and **ndepend**, but neither were able to find the source of that namespace. I'm not sure the source is even available anymore, but I'm trying to at least find the imported dll.

Any ideas?

**Update:** **Solved**  - it was in a .cs file in the /app_code directory of the web application.

Comment: I would also check your [Temporary ASP.NET Files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/450912/2344773).

Comment: Use textual search in totalcmd for instance... Look through your App_Code as well...

Comment: @rocky - that was the ticket. /App_code in the wwwroot.

Comment: I've added it as an answer. Will be glad if you mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use textual search in totalcmd for instance... Look through your App_Code as well..

**Note:** /App_Code is found in the root of your Kentico instance in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched across all dll's? The namespace may not necessarily match the assembly name. But from how it's imported I'd assume it's in the same assembly of the ascx you're referring to.

It may well be a namespace created in any .cs file that is compiled with the custom module.